# PHP tmpfile() returns false

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, temporary-files

I've got an image upload script which was previously working.  It's now broken, and I've traced the problem down to one line:

```
$temp = tmpfile();
// $temp === false
```

The tmpfile() function is returning false.  I can't seem to figure out why.  I'm having a hard time wading through Google on this one.

The script it only broken on my local test environment, OSX 10.6.7, running MAMP 1.9.5.  Fortunately the live site is working fine.

Comment: From the manual: `tmpfile() Returns a file handle, similar to the one returned by fopen(), for the new file or FALSE on failure.` So something's failing, maybe permissions?

Comment: You should check that you have the right permissions to create a file.

Comment: Why do people leave answers in comments?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[tmpfile()](http://fi.php.net/tmpfile) returns `false` if it is unable to create the temporary file. Make sure your tmp folder is writable and try and check what `sys_get_temp_dir()` function returns.

Comment: sys_get_temp_dir() returns: /var/folders/pl/plwnvK1yE7ekOV2cHWtpAk+++TI/-Tmp-

Comment: I chmod 777 that dir, and the script works again.  What could have changed the temp dir?  I would have expected it to be set to /var/tmp.

Comment: Hi Niklas, I have a question related to your reply. Due to what I readh in tmpfile() php doc, it basically says that the temporary file will be created and set to w+, which is writable, so why do we need to chmod it to 777?

Comment: @BeingSimpler I never said that you need to chmod it 777. The tmp folder permissions should be however such, that the script has write permissions there. Same way as `fopen(sys_get_temp_dir().$file, 'w+')` would function.

Comment: tmpfile() is returning false for me as well. I can't use sys_get_temp_dir as I'm on PHP5.1.6. If I test my upload_tmp_dir with is_writable() it returns true. Has anyone got any ideas? thanks

Comment: I tried your solution but to no avail. /tmp is set to 777 and sys_get_temp_dir() returns /tmp but tmpfile() still returns false (so do other /tmp file functions such as move_uploaded_file). I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 3):

It might be a problem with permissions.
Use `sys_get_temp_dir()` to see where the temp file will be created and make sure php has access to write there.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the folder it was trying to create the file in had temp files ranging all the way up to tmpFFFF.tmp.  After moving those temp files away from the folder, it started back at tmp1.tmp.

Answer (score 0):

First, enable all PHP warnings to see if it is telling you something.

Second, check your temp folder and make sure PHP has write access to it. It's possible that certain "safe mode" restrictions (base dirs, etc) are preventing access.