# tmpfile() PHP returing false though upload_tmp_dir is writable

Tags: php, upload, temporary-files

I'm trying to use `tmpfile()`  but is returning false for me.

I can't use `sys_get_temp_dir()` as I'm on PHP5.1.6 as posters on similar issues have suggested but if I test my `upload_tmp_dir` (is this the same value as `sys_get_temp_dir()`?) with `is_writable()` it returns true.

Apparently according to responses the tmp directory is likely to be different to the upload_tmp_dir. The problem is none of the methods of finding out the tmp directory work:
`$_ENV['tmp']`, `$_ENV['temp']` and `$_ENV['tmpdir']` are empty. Also the following code won't work as `tempnam()` fails,presumably the same reason `tmpfile()` does.

```
$temp=tempnam(__FILE__,'');
if (file_exists($temp)) {
    unlink($temp);
    return dirname($temp);
}
```

Has anyone got any more suggestions?
Could it be a server configuration issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tmpfile()` doesn't upload files, it creates temporary files in you system tmp folder.

Without `sys_get_temp_dir()` you could try and get the tmp dir with one of these:

```
getenv('TMP');
getenv('TEMP');
getenv('TMPDIR');
```

There are multiple examples of how to [use them there](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) and once you find it, see if its writable.

The only reason `tmpfile()` returns false is if its not able to create the file. Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267807/php-tmpfile-returns-false/6267842#6267842).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `open_basedir` option is enabled on your server.

You should not emit the errors or check your error.log, the warning message should be there.

Comment: Dear user who was so kind to gave me a -1, could you *please* comment here the why? Or submit your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an `open_basedir` issue:

> Remember, that open_basedir affects
>   this function. You will get an error:
>
> Warning: tmpfile() [function.tmpfile]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/tmp) is not within the
>   allowed path(s): ....blablabla =)

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php#74623

Also, `sys_get_temp_dir` is NOT the same as `upload_tmp_dir`.

To emulate this `sys_get_temp_dir` in older PHP versions, try this:

```
<?php
if ( !function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
  function sys_get_temp_dir() {
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMP'])) { return realpath($_ENV['TMP']); }
    if (!empty($_ENV['TMPDIR'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TMPDIR']); }
    if (!empty($_ENV['TEMP'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TEMP']); }
    $tempfile=tempnam(uniqid(rand(),TRUE),'');
    if (file_exists($tempfile)) {
    unlink($tempfile);
    return realpath(dirname($tempfile));
    }
  }
}
?>
```

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php#85261

Comment: phpinfo says open_basedir has no value. Does this mean it is not enabled?

Comment: Yes. In this case, `open_basedir` is not your problem. I have added more info in my answer... please, check. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately none of those vars are set. I printed out the $_ENV array and there's nothing containing a path to a tmp directory. Do you think this is a server configuration issue? thanks