# MAMP on Windows gives empty $_FILES on basic file upload

Tags: php, windows, file-upload, mamp

I'm using MAMP for Windows. I need just a basic script to upload a video file so that I can put it in a known directory for a native windows application. I started with code I grabbed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839127/php-video-upload-script) for a template to go off of, but my preliminary tests have revealed that it's not as easy to just upload a file with MAMP on Windows.

I've modified it a little bit and it looks like this:

**video-form.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="video-up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**video-up.php**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("mov");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ( $_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/quicktime" && in_array($extension, $allowedExts) )
{
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }   
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid file";
}

?>
<br><br>$_FILES
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES);
?>
</pre> 
<br><br>$_POST
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump($_FILES);
?>
</pre> 
<br><br>$_GET
<pre>
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
?>
</pre>
```

I put `$_FILES` `$_POST` & `$_GET` there just to see what I was gettin, but the output of video-up.php after being given a video file is a bunch of blank arrays.

```
Invalid file

$_FILES
array(0) {
}


$_POST
array(0) {
}


$_GET
array(0) {
}
```

The file uploads section of the php.ini looks like this:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
upload_tmp_dir = C:\MAMP\temp

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 200M


; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Any help as to why php doesn't seem to recognize the upload is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also make sure the folder has proper permissions to write to it.

Comment: Try looking in the log files also. It's likely your issue is with your temporary files folder. Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267807/php-tmpfile-returns-false

Comment: @Fred-ii-

I added display errors and it gave me the Timezone thing that I always forget to do, but other than that it only showed that `'file'` is not a valid index to an array that is empty. As for write permissions, I do seem to have some trouble getting MAMP to recognize the correct directory as my temp directory. I changed it in php.ini to `C:\MAMP\temp`, but when I use `sys_get_temp_dir()` it shows it as `C:\Users\MYUSER~1\AppData\Local\Temp`. That seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: @stubben As I said in the comment above, I do seem to have some trouble getting MAMP to recognize the correct directory as my temp directory. I changed it in php.ini to `C:\MAMP\temp`, but when I use `sys_get_temp_dir()` it shows it as `C:\Users\MYUSER~1\AppData\Local\Temp`. That seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Using `tmpfile()` returns `Resource id #2`, though, which seems to indicate that the temp directory is valid, despite it being in a different place than I thought it would be.

Comment: Have you restarted your web server after changing the php.ini file?

Comment: @stubben yep. multiple times just to make sure I wasn't crazy.

Comment: @stubben if I print out with `phpinfo()` it shows my upload_tmp_dir is `C:\MAMP\temp`. I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with a different `.mov` file and the upload now recognizes the file. I'm not sure what the difference between those two files are that would cause one to not be recognized/uploaded at all while the other works, but when I find out I will update this answer.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out there are two settings in php.ini that need to be tweaked that affect the allowed file size. One being the specific one of `upload_max_filesize` and the other being general to the size of the entire post request itself: `post_max_size`.

The `post_max_size` setting doesn't show an error on the page with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, but will put it in the php error log. It will actually be a warning and look something like this:

`PHP Warning: POST Content-Length of 8708224 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0`

I believe the default size is 8M for that setting.